# 'Extra Argument in Call' in completion call in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, tuples

I am trying to return a simple tuple in the completion of a function as in the following code:

```
func meditatorForId(id:Int, completion:((Meditator, Int)? -> Void)){
    var counter:Int=0
    for meditator in SanghaModelProvider.sharedProvider().meditatorsArray{
        if meditator.id == id{
            completion(meditator, counter)
            return
        }
        counter+=1
    }
    completion(nil)
}
```

Yet I get 'Extra Argument in Call' on the completion call line without getting more explanations. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call completion with two arguments, but it should be a single argument with the tuple:

```
completion((meditator, counter))
```

i.e.:

```
let tuple = (meditator, counter)
completion(tuple)
```

If you would prefer to call it with two parameters then change your function to this:

```
func meditatorForId(id:Int, completion:((Meditator?, Int?) -> Void)) {
```

Then this will work:

```
completion(meditator, counter)
```

but you will have to change the 2nd call to:

```
completion(nil, nil)
```

Comment: So addio the quotino mark outside the parenthesis turned the into a tuple, while inserting it inside keeps the as parameters. Very interesting, thanks.